# 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 24: invalid start byte

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read a `csv` file using the following lines of `Python` code:

```
crimes = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/usuario1/Desktop/python/csv/001 Boston crimes/crime.csv', encoding = 'utf8')
crimes.head(5)
```

But I am getting decode error as follws:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 24: invalid start byte
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: Can you post an example of the CSV file?

Answer (score 2):

May be your file does not support `utf-8` codec or has a character that does not support `utf-8`. You can try other encodings like `ISO-8859-1`. But it is best to check your file encoding first. To do so, something like the following should work:
1.

```
    with open('Your/file/path') as f:
        print(f)
```

This should print file details with encoding.

2. Or you can just open the csv and when you go to File -> Save As this should show your encoding.
3. If those don't help, you can ignore the  rows that are causing problems by using `error_bad_lines=False'

   ```
   crimes = pd.read_csv('Your/file/path', encoding='utf8', error_bad_lines=False)
   ```

   Hope these will help

Comment: Hello Niaz, thanks for your answer! I´ve tried point 1 and is giving me the following message: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:/Users/usuario1/Desktop/python/csv/001 Boston crimes/crime.csv' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'> I'm not sure about what does it mean...

Comment: cp1252 is your file's encoding type. Can you try `crimes = pd.read_csv('Your/file/path', encoding='cp1252')` This link can help you https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/10424#issuecomment-326572248